# Probability of a student owning a car

Tags: probability

Right now I'm stuck on the following problem, since I feel like I should be using total probability, but I dont know what numbers to use as what.

Let's say there's a population of students. In this population:

30% have a bike

10% have a motorcycle

12% have a car.

8% have a bike AND a motorcycle

7% car and a bike

4% have a motorcycle and a car

2% have a bike, a car and a motorcycle

What percentage of students owns no vehicles?

I draw myself a Venn diagram, but I can't get my mind around the problem. My thinking right now is just substracting each percentage off 100%, but that just feels wrong.

Using total probability feels wrong aswell, since I have no idea what to calculate. I want to calculate P(A) = people that own a vehicle, but then P(A|Hi) doesn't really have a value.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Well...as there are three types of vehicles there are $2^3=8$ possible states of a student.  You are given  $6$ bits of information and the fact that all the states must add to $100\%$ is a $7^{th}$ bit so on first pass it looks like you need more information. Still, I suggest writing out each of the $8$ states and computing their percentages as far as you are able.

Comment: @DavidMitra edited. Missed a data point

Comment: 8% bike and car, 7% car and bike?.

Comment: @user8734617 yup I actually messed up retyping the assignment. Still not making any progress though.

Comment: But now you can complete your Venn diagram: 2% in the middle, 6% have only bike and motorcycle (but not car) etc. Go from the centre outwards.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the full universe of people (100%), subtract out all of the people who own a mode of transportation (30%, 10%, 12%). You have double counted some people, so add back in the people who have two modes of transportation. Now, you have added back the people who own all modes too many times, so you need to subtract them out again.

Imagine you have three circular pieces of paper. What you want is to cut the pieces of paper so that everything is covered and no areas are overlapping. This way you will only count a type of person once. Subtract that number from 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the set of students with a bicycle; let $C$ be the set of students with a car; let $M$ be the set of students with a motorcycle.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability that a student has a vehicle is 
$$P(B) \cup P(C) \cup P(M) = P(B) + P(C) + P(M) - P(B \cap C) - P(B \cap M) - P(C \cap M) + P(B \cap C \cap M)$$
The percentage of students who owe no vehicles is $1 - P(B \cup C \cup M)$.

To see why this formula holds, consider the Venn diagram below.

[image: Venn_diagram_for_vehicle_problem]

Observe that simply adding the probabilities that a student owns a particular type of vehicle counts each student who owns two types of vehicles twice, once for each type of vehicle the student owns.  Since we only want to count them once, we must subtract $P(B \cap C) + P(B \cap M) + P(C \cap M)$ from $P(B) + P(C) + P(M)$.  Alas, doing so means we have not counted students who own all three types of vehicles at all.  This is because we counted such students three times when we added the probabilities that they own a vehicle and subtracted them three times when we subtracted the probabilities that a student owns two types of vehicles.  Since we wish to include those students, we must add $P(B \cap C \cap M)$.